# Get parent directory's parent directory name in java

Tags: java, filepath

I have current working file's directory path `I:\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\ExecutableFileProcess\WEB-INF\classes\PackageName\`

I want path like `I:\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\ExecutableFileProcess\`. How can I do this in java code?

Comment: Do you like to have the absolute or the relative name?

Comment: what do you mean by "the absolute or the relative name"

Comment: Is ok, i saw your example.

Comment: Don't you rather want javax.servlet.ServletContext.getRealPath("/"), than a parent of parent?

Answer (score 1):

You better get your App-Path from the `ServletContext` in Servlet-Containern like Tomcat.

Use

```
servletContext.getRealPath(".");
// will return 'I:\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\ExecutableFileProcess\' on win.
// will return '/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ExecutableFileProcess' on unix.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getParentFile()

Applying this twice will probably get you the right directory.

But note that you program might or might not be allowed to go there, based on the settings in the file system and the context your code runs in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
Path aPath = Paths.get("I:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\\webapps\\ExecutableFileProcess\\WEB-INF\\classes\PackageName\\");
Path parentsParentpath = aPath.getParent().getParent();
```